# Truncate (NOT ROUND) decimal numbers in Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

Do you know a way of truncating decimal numbers (not round) in **mapping data flow** in Azure Data Factory?

Example:

**Input:** 123.456

**Output:** 123.45 (not 123.46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **round(123.456,2,4)** --> 2 is the post characters, 4 is the round option - **FLOOR**